# trying to use _.sortBy method to sort an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, object, underscore.js

I have tried EVERY solution I can find, and nothing is working.

I have an array of objects, which in the HTML is a dropdown menu. I can not get it to sort. Here is my code:

```
$scope.materials = []

var Material = function(materialName) {

    this.name = materialName;

    $scope.materials.push(this);



}

_.sortBy($scope.materials, function(object){
    return object.name; 
    });
```

//==========below are some of my objects that I am pushing into the array(I'm planning to add more properties to them later besides just a 'name'================//

```
var pipeCleaners = new Material ('pipe cleaners')
var glitter = new Material ('glitter')
var pomPoms = new Material (' pom poms')
var feathers = new Material ('feathers')
var cottonBalls = new Material ('cotton balls')
```

Comment: http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy *"**Returns** a (stably) sorted **copy** of list"*

Comment: i.e., this is not an "in-place" sort.

Answer (score 5):

sortBy doesn't modify the array, you actually have to assign the returned array of sortBy to a variable.

```
var x = _.sortBy([1, 2, 3], function(n) {
  return Math.sin(n);
});
console.log(x); // [3, 1, 2]
```